# Is it meaningful to remove layers with %100 sparsity in a CNN - VGG 16

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, vgg-net

I am training an autoencoder by using VGG-16 as feature extraction. Whenever I check the sparsity (number of parameters equal to zero / total parameters) of the blocks, I noticed that Block 5 (deepest block of VGG-16) has %100 sparsity. As it is the most time consuming block for VGG architecture, I would like to remove it if possible.

So, is it meaningful to remove CNN layers with %100 sparsity to increase performance as all of them are actually equal to zero?

Comment: I once did the same thing to a custom model . The accuracy was not affected after removing the sparse layer. However, it is difficult to generalize that removing such layers will not affect the performance of the model. One more thing to consider is the shape of the data. If you remove that particular layer then the shapes have to be managed appropriately

Comment: Thanks, it was a meaningful approach